# Update Error from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS :- Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I want to Upgrade From Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
So i ran The Following Command's

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d -f DistUpgradeViewGtk3
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

Then I Ran The Following Command to upgrade pacakges

```
sudo apt update

Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease           
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease            
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease            
Reading package lists... Done                      
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.


apt list --upgradable

Listing... Done
gdb/bionic-updates 8.1.1-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5]
gir1.2-peas-1.0/bionic 1.22.0-2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.0-1ubuntu2]
libpeas-1.0-0/bionic 1.22.0-2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.16.0-1ubuntu2]


sudo apt upgrade -y

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  gdb gir1.2-peas-1.0 libpeas-1.0-0
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

These 3 pacakes were not upgraded **gdb gir1.2-peas-1.0 libpeas-1.0-0** which were stopping me from upgrading so i tried these command's

```
sudo apt install gir1.2-peas-1.0

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gir1.2-peas-1.0 : Depends: libpeas-1.0-0 (>= 1.18.0) but 1.16.0-1ubuntu2 is to be installed


sudo apt install libpeas-1.0-0

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpeas-1.0-0 : Depends: libpython3.6 (>= 3.6.4~rc1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


sudo apt install gdb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gdb : Depends: libpython3.6 (>= 3.6.5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.



sudo apt-mark hold

E: No packages found


sudo apt full-upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  gdb gir1.2-peas-1.0 libpeas-1.0-0
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.


sudo apt-cache policy gdb
gdb:
  Installed: 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5
  Candidate: 8.1.1-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     8.1.1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
     8.1-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status



sudo apt-cache policy libpeas-1.0-0

libpeas-1.0-0:
  Installed: 1.16.0-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1.22.0-2
  Version table:
     1.22.0-2 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.16.0-1ubuntu2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status



sudo apt-cache policy gir1.2-peas-1.0

gir1.2-peas-1.0:
  Installed: 1.16.0-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1.22.0-2
  Version table:
     1.22.0-2 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.16.0-1ubuntu2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Please help Me !

Comment: Check you don't have any held packages (`apt-mark hold` type), you have `apt full-upgrade`.. however your messages don't comply with a fully-updated *bionic* or 18.04 system which should have `libpeas-1.0-0 | 1.22.0-2        | bionic  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x` and not the package in your messages, so I'd check your sources, and where you grabbed the package you do have installed (is it 3rd party?  `apt-cache policy` to look) etc.

Comment: Please don't provide extra details via comment, edit your question & add the detail there (it's easier to red, formatting is better etc).

Comment: @guiverc I have added all  the extra detail in the question

Comment: FYI:  It can't find the `gdb` package when it's typed as 'gbd' so that one is easy.  I also looked up your mirror & it's *up-to-date* according to https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors  can't currently read the rest (busy)

Comment: @guiverc I Corrected My Mistake In it from `gbd` to `gdb` and edited it in the question

Comment: Save a text file containing commands to install these packages again after update. For now, unistall these packages and also run autoremove. Then upgrade your OS. Install these packages again after update.

Comment: @Master_Nachi Thanks, this worked and the OS is now upgrading, but I still wonder why these were not upgrading.

Comment: I have made this the answer. Pls click on tick to accept the answer. I don`t know why they were not upgrading. I faced same problem with audacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save a text file containing commands to install these packages again after update. For now, unistall these packages and also run autoremove. Then upgrade your OS. Install these packages again after update.